# How to copy text, which is in a for-each loop, to clipboard when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a for-each loop which prints out some text from a database and also displays a button. So essentially I have multiple "areas" of text and each with their own button. I want it so that whenever a user clicks on a button, that specific text it is matched up with is copied to the clipboard.

I tried doing multiple searches on this before posting on here. However, from the other solutions, I read they more or less show a solution for copying text in an input tag. However, in my case the user is not typing anything in that needs to get copied - the text is already on the screen and can't be changed.

I am having trouble with copying that specific text that matches a button since the text does not have a specific id or class name because it is just printing text as it goes through the loop, so they all have the same class name. So how would I specify a specific text with that button, since the buttons could get pressed in any order?

HTML:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
<h2>${item.itemDescription}</h2>
<input class="big-button" type="button" value="Add item copied to clipboard" id="btn" onclick="status(this)">
</c:forEach>
```

JavaScript:

```
function status(clickedBtn) 
  {
    clickedBtn.value = "Copied to clipboard";
    clickedBtn.disabled = true;
    clickedBtn.style.color = 'white';
    clickedBtn.style.background = 'gray';
  }
```

Comment: I've used this answer to get text onto the clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928558/74757. You could use a selector to get the text from the `<h2>` item and pass that.

Comment: You could use the index of the item in the loop to generate an id too, so you can reference your element easier.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, thanks so much for linking that. So, I checked it out and it seems like they are able to do `new Date()` which copies the date to the clipboard. However, in my case, I have to copy the string that is is in the loop -- `${item.itemDescription}`. So, how would I be able to call that, since that is in my HTML, and not in the JS.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ oh okay that makes sense. Sorry, I am still new to HTML and JS. how would I be able to reference a certain index, since I theoretically don't know how many elements there are since I am getting the information from the database and inserting into my HTML.

Comment: What templating framework are you using?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I have this at the top of my HTML, `<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` which is allowing me to use that for each loop.

Comment: I've written an answer that has a working example of everything tied together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your HTML to generate some kind of ID that can be used to reference the element with your text.

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <h2 id="item-desc-${loop.index}">${item.itemDescription}</h2>
    <input class="big-button" data-desc-ref="item-desc-${loop.index}" type="button" value="Add item copied to clipboard" id="btn" onclick="status(this)">
</c:forEach>
```

Above I added code to generate a unique id (e.g. `id="item-desc-0"`) on each `<h2>` element. On the button, I added a `data-` attribute to reference the ID of the `<h2>` so we can retrieve it later.

Now we change your `status` function to find the element by the ID specified in the data attribute, and get its `innerText` (the content between the opening and closing tags).

Then, you can pass that text to the function that copies it to the clipboard, reference above in my comment.

```
  function status(clickedBtn) 
  {
    var text = document.getElementById(clickedBtn.dataset.descRef).innerText;
    copyToClipboard(text);

    clickedBtn.value = "Copied to clipboard";
    clickedBtn.disabled = true;
    clickedBtn.style.color = 'white';
    clickedBtn.style.background = 'gray';
  }
```

Here's a working example. I had to put in sample HTML that would be generated by your loop.

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
    // IE specific code path to prevent textarea being shown while dialog is visible.
    return clipboardData.setData("Text", text);

  } else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.textContent = text;
    textarea.style.position = "fixed"; // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in MS Edge.
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.select();
    try {
      return document.execCommand("copy"); // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
      return false;
    } finally {
      document.body.removeChild(textarea);
    }
  }
}

function status(clickedBtn) {
  var text = document.getElementById(clickedBtn.dataset.descRef).innerText;

  copyToClipboard(text);

  clickedBtn.value = "Copied to clipboard";
  clickedBtn.disabled = true;
  clickedBtn.style.color = 'white';
  clickedBtn.style.background = 'gray';
}
```

```html
<h2 id="item-desc-0">Testing 0</h2>
<input class="big-button" data-desc-ref="item-desc-0" type="button" value="Add item copied to clipboard" id="btn" onclick="status(this)">

<h2 id="item-desc-1">Testing 1</h2>
<input class="big-button" data-desc-ref="item-desc-1" type="button" value="Add item copied to clipboard" id="btn" onclick="status(this)">

<h2 id="item-desc-2">Testing 2</h2>
<input class="big-button" data-desc-ref="item-desc-2" type="button" value="Add item copied to clipboard" id="btn" onclick="status(this)">
```

Comment: @Cory, thanks so much for this! I tried it and unfortunately, it's not working. When do you set the index number for the for-each loop?

Comment: I supplied some modified JSTL code that renders the HTML a little differently. Did you remember to update your JSTL?

Comment: @Cory, You deserve the goldest of stars!!! THIS WORKED!!! wow you are incredible!!! thank you so much!! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Please study it and understand it, and reach back if any part of it didn't make sense. It will be beneficial to fully understand why it works so you can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

If `h2` element exactly is on `previous` of `button` you can use like this.

```js
function status(clickedBtn) 
    {
      clickedBtn.value = "Copied to clipboard";
      clickedBtn.disabled = true;
      clickedBtn.style.color = 'white';
      clickedBtn.style.background = 'gray';

      //New Code
      copyToCliboard(clickedBtn.previousSibling);
    }
    function copyToCliboard(el) {
      if (document.body.createTextRange) {
          var range = document.body.createTextRange();
          range.moveToElementText(el);
          range.select();
      } else {
          var selection = window.getSelection();
          var range = document.createRange();
          range.selectNodeContents(el);
          selection.removeAllRanges();
          selection.addRange(range);
      }
      document.execCommand("copy");
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
```

```css
h2{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
 </head>
  <body>
   <div><h2>Text1</h2><button onclick="status(this)">Copy</button></div>
   <div><h2>Text2</h2><button onclick="status(this)">Copy</button></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cory provides a very helpful link to the clipboard aspect, I thought I'd provide the info about how to target a clicked element.

To achieve this, pass `event` to your onclick attribute, and use `event.target` to reference the clicked element. Here's a basic example:

```js
function copy(e) {
 alert(e.target.value)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copy(event)" value="copy this">copy this</button>
<button onclick="copy(event)" value="copy that">copy that</button>
```

To address your specific requirement, if you put `item.itemDescription` into the `value` attribute, then it will copy the text you want.

Comment: thanks so much! So since I already have something in my `value` attribute, is there another way around this?

Comment: @daisygal sure, you could probably do something like use a [parent selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp) and then find the `h2` value from there.